# How Use DependencyInjection in GenericRepository and UnitOfWork

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, dependency-injection, repository-pattern

I have a WindowsForm Project With this design :
DAL(GenericRepository  => UnitOfWork)    =>  BLL(Service)   =>   UI
And use EntityFramWork, Interface, GenericRepository, Dependency Injection

My Code in Repository(DAL) :

```
public class Repository : RepositoryBase, IDisposable, IRepository where T : class  
{  
       private readonly DbSet dbSet;  
       private bool disposed = false;
       public Repository(GlobalERPEntities dbContext)  
       {  
           DBContext = dbContext;  
           dbSet = DBContext.Set();  
       }    
       public virtual IEnumerable GetAll()  
       {  
           return dbSet.ToList();  
       } 
}
```

UnitOfWork(DAL) :

```
public class UnitOfWork : RepositoryBase, IUnitOfWork, IDisposable  
   {  
       private Dictionaryobject> repositories;  
       private bool disposed = false;  

       public UnitOfWork(GlobalERPEntities dbContext)  
       {  
           DBContext = dbContext;  
       }  

       public IRepository Repository() where T : class  
       {  
           if (repositories == null)  
           {  
               repositories = new Dictionaryobject>();  
           }  

           if (repositories.Keys.Contains(typeof(T)) == true)  
           {  
               return repositories[typeof(T)] as Repository;  
           }  
           Repository repo = new Repository(DBContext);  
           repositories.Add(typeof(T), repo);  
           return repo;  
       }
```

Service(BLL) :

```
public class Service_HR_Person : IService_HR_Person ,  IDisposable  
   {  
       private readonly IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork;  

       public Service_HR_Person(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)  
       {  
           UnitOfWork = unitOfWork;  
       }  

       public virtual IEnumerable GetAll()  
       {  
           return UnitOfWork.Repository().GetAll().ToList();  
       }
```

MyForm(UI) :

```
using (Service_HR_Person srvPerson = new Service_HR_Person())  
               {  
                   srvPerson.Delete(base.rowid);  
                   try  
                   {  
                       srvPerson.Save();
                       MessageManager.Show(Enums.MessageBoxType.InformationTransactionSuccessfully);  
                   }  
                   catch (Exception ex)  
                   {  
                       MessageManager.Show(ErrorManager.ProccessException(ex), Enums.MessageBoxType.Error);  
                   }  
               }
```

Iknow should not use DAL Layer in UI layer and BLL is between DAL and UI
but i have error in ui

```
using (Service_HR_Person srvPerson = new Service_HR_Person())
```

"new Service_HR_Person()" say need an arguman in () that is unitofwork but we should not use unitofwork in UI

i read some article and sample that use IOC , ninject ,bootstraper and ... but i cant write true code
How To use Ninject or IOC?
please help me with code
thankyou

Comment: This question is a bit too broad for StackoverFlow. Ideally you provide us with a sample of something you tried that isn't working and an exact explanation of what you want to tachieve. Have a look here for more information on how to use DI in windows forms and open a new question when you have a specific question: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/122238/use-of-ninject-as-an-ioc-container-in-a-winforms-mvc-application

Comment: @Kenneth thankyou. is good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a new project to solution with name "Configure"
add castle.windsor from NuGet to all project
add a class to this project with name "Bootstrapper" and write this code

```
public static WindsorContainer Container = null;

   public static void WireUp()
   {
                    Container = new WindsorContainer();
                    Container.Register(Component.For<GlobalERPEntities>());
                    Container.Register(Component.For<IUnitOfWork>().ImplementedBy<UnitOfWork>());
                    Container.Register(Component.For<IService_HR_Person>().ImplementedBy<Service_HR_Person>());
   }
```

and edit your code in UI

```
 using (Service_HR_Person srvPerson = Bootstrapper.Container.Resolve<Service_HR_Person>())
                {
                    srvPerson.Delete(base.rowid);
                    try
                    {
                        srvPerson.Save();
                        RemoveRow();
                        MessageManager.Show(Enums.MessageBoxType.InformationTransactionSuccessfully);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageManager.Show(ErrorManager.ProccessException(ex), Enums.MessageBoxType.Error);
                    }
                }
```

this line

```
 using (Service_HR_Person srvPerson = Bootstrapper.Container.Resolve<Service_HR_Person>())
```

and edit Program.cs with this code

```
 static void Main(string[] argss)
        {
            Bootstrapper.WireUp();
```

this is work corectly